# Tortoise-tts modification for multiple texts generation

Tags: python, text-to-speech

I wanted to modify the do_tts script code so that it reads the -text attribute from the config.json file. Then to have it execute in a loop for different texts in the config file and save them under different names adding text_id to file name. Unfortunately, I have a problem. After the modifications made, the script does not run, without any errors... Just not starting.

I have checked:

```
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG)
```

and after running

```
(tortoise-tts) C:\Users\PrimoPC\anaconda3\tortoise-tts>python tortoise/do_tts.py --config config.json
```

this is what it says:

```
DEBUG:torchaudio._extension:Failed to initialize ffmpeg bindings
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PrimoPC\anaconda3\envs\tortoise-tts\lib\site-packages\torchaudio\_extension\utils.py", line 85, in _init_ffmpeg
    _load_lib("libtorchaudio_ffmpeg")
  File "C:\Users\PrimoPC\anaconda3\envs\tortoise-tts\lib\site-packages\torchaudio\_extension\utils.py", line 61, in _load_lib
    torch.ops.load_library(path)
  File "C:\Users\PrimoPC\anaconda3\envs\tortoise-tts\lib\site-packages\torch\_ops.py", line 643, in load_library
    ctypes.CDLL(path)
  File "C:\Users\PrimoPC\anaconda3\envs\tortoise-tts\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\PrimoPC\anaconda3\envs\tortoise-tts\Lib\site-packages\torchaudio\lib\libtorchaudio_ffmpeg.pyd' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PrimoPC\anaconda3\envs\tortoise-tts\lib\site-packages\torchaudio\_extension\__init__.py", line 67, in <module>
    _init_ffmpeg()
  File "C:\Users\PrimoPC\anaconda3\envs\tortoise-tts\lib\site-packages\torchaudio\_extension\utils.py", line 87, in _init_ffmpeg
    raise ImportError("FFmpeg libraries are not found. Please install FFmpeg.") from err
ImportError: FFmpeg libraries are not found. Please install FFmpeg.
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): huggingface.co:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://huggingface.co:443 "HEAD /jbetker/wav2vec2-large-robust-ft-libritts-voxpopuli/resolve/main/config.json HTTP/1.1" 200 0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): huggingface.co:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://huggingface.co:443 "HEAD /jbetker/wav2vec2-large-robust-ft-libritts-voxpopuli/resolve/main/pytorch_model.bin HTTP/1.1" 302 0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): huggingface.co:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://huggingface.co:443 "HEAD /facebook/wav2vec2-large-960h/resolve/main/preprocessor_config.json HTTP/1.1" 200 0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): huggingface.co:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://huggingface.co:443 "HEAD /jbetker/tacotron-symbols/resolve/main/vocab.json HTTP/1.1" 200 0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): huggingface.co:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://huggingface.co:443 "HEAD /jbetker/tacotron-symbols/resolve/main/tokenizer_config.json HTTP/1.1" 200 0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): huggingface.co:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://huggingface.co:443 "HEAD /jbetker/tacotron-symbols/resolve/main/added_tokens.json HTTP/1.1" 404 0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): huggingface.co:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://huggingface.co:443 "HEAD /jbetker/tacotron-symbols/resolve/main/special_tokens_map.json HTTP/1.1" 200 0
```

Orginal code:

```
import argparse
import os

import torch
import torchaudio

from api import TextToSpeech, MODELS_DIR
from utils.audio import load_voices

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--text', type=str, help='Text to speak.', default="The expressiveness of autoregressive transformers is literally nuts! I absolutely adore them.")
    parser.add_argument('--voice', type=str, help='Selects the voice to use for generation. See options in voices/ directory (and add your own!) '
                                                 'Use the & character to join two voices together. Use a comma to perform inference on multiple voices.', default='random')
    parser.add_argument('--preset', type=str, help='Which voice preset to use.', default='fast')
    parser.add_argument('--output_path', type=str, help='Where to store outputs.', default='results/')
    parser.add_argument('--model_dir', type=str, help='Where to find pretrained model checkpoints. Tortoise automatically downloads these to .models, so this'
                                                      'should only be specified if you have custom checkpoints.', default=MODELS_DIR)
    parser.add_argument('--candidates', type=int, help='How many output candidates to produce per-voice.', default=3)
    parser.add_argument('--seed', type=int, help='Random seed which can be used to reproduce results.', default=None)
    parser.add_argument('--produce_debug_state', type=bool, help='Whether or not to produce debug_state.pth, which can aid in reproducing problems. Defaults to true.', default=True)
    parser.add_argument('--cvvp_amount', type=float, help='How much the CVVP model should influence the output.'
                                                          'Increasing this can in some cases reduce the likelihood of multiple speakers. Defaults to 0 (disabled)', default=.0)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    os.makedirs(args.output_path, exist_ok=True)

    tts = TextToSpeech(models_dir=args.model_dir)

    selected_voices = args.voice.split(',')
    for k, selected_voice in enumerate(selected_voices):
        if '&' in selected_voice:
            voice_sel = selected_voice.split('&')
        else:
            voice_sel = [selected_voice]
        voice_samples, conditioning_latents = load_voices(voice_sel)

        gen, dbg_state = tts.tts_with_preset(args.text, k=args.candidates, voice_samples=voice_samples, conditioning_latents=conditioning_latents,
                                  preset=args.preset, use_deterministic_seed=args.seed, return_deterministic_state=True, cvvp_amount=args.cvvp_amount)
        if isinstance(gen, list):
            for j, g in enumerate(gen):
                torchaudio.save(os.path.join(args.output_path, f'{selected_voice}_{k}_{j}.wav'), g.squeeze(0).cpu(), 24000)
        else:
            torchaudio.save(os.path.join(args.output_path, f'{selected_voice}_{k}.wav'), gen.squeeze(0).cpu(), 24000)

        if args.produce_debug_state:
            os.makedirs('debug_states', exist_ok=True)
            torch.save(dbg_state, f'debug_states/do_tts_debug_{selected_voice}.pth')
```

Modified code:

```
import argparse
import os
import json
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG)
import torch
import torchaudio

from api import TextToSpeech, MODELS_DIR
from utils.audio import load_voices

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--config', type=str, help='Path to the config file.', default='config.json')
    parser.add_argument('--voice', type=str, help='Selects the voice to use for generation. See options in voices/ directory (and add your own!) '
                                                 'Use the & character to join two voices together. Use a comma to perform inference on multiple voices.', default='random')
    parser.add_argument('--preset', type=str, help='Which voice preset to use.', default='fast')
    parser.add_argument('--output_path', type=str, help='Where to store outputs.', default='results/')
    parser.add_argument('--model_dir', type=str, help='Where to find pretrained model checkpoints. Tortoise automatically downloads these to .models, so this'
                                                      'should only be specified if you have custom checkpoints.', default=MODELS_DIR)
    parser.add_argument('--candidates', type=int, help='How many output candidates to produce per-voice.', default=1)
    parser.add_argument('--seed', type=int, help='Random seed which can be used to reproduce results.', default=None)
    parser.add_argument('--produce_debug_state', type=bool, help='Whether or not to produce debug_state.pth, which can aid in reproducing problems. Defaults to true.', default=True)
    parser.add_argument('--cvvp_amount', type=float, help='How much the CVVP model should influence the output.'
                                                          'Increasing this can in some cases reduce the likelihood of multiple speakers. Defaults to 0 (disabled)', default=.0)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    config_file = args.config

    if not os.path.isfile(config_file):
        raise FileNotFoundError(f"Config file '{config_file}' not found.")

    # Odczyt pliku config.json
    with open(config_file, 'r') as f:
        config = json.load(f)

    texts = config.get('texts', [])

    os.makedirs(args.output_path, exist_ok=True)

    tts = TextToSpeech(models_dir=args.model_dir)

    selected_voices = args.voice.split(',')
    for k, selected_voice in enumerate(selected_voices):
        if '&' in selected_voice:
            voice_sel = selected_voice.split('&')
        else:
            voice_sel = [selected_voice]
        voice_samples, conditioning_latents = load_voices(voice_sel)

        for text in texts:
            text_id = text.get('id', '')
            text_content = text.get('text', '')
            gen, dbg_state = tts.tts_with_preset(text_content, k=args.candidates, voice_samples=voice_samples, conditioning_latents=conditioning_latents,
                                      preset=args.preset, use_deterministic_seed=args.seed, return_deterministic_state=True, cvvp_amount=args.cvvp_amount)
            if isinstance(gen, list):
                for j, g in enumerate(gen):
                    torchaudio.save(os.path.join(args.output_path, f'{selected_voice}_{k}_{text_id}_{j}.wav'), g.squeeze(0).cpu(), 24000)
            else:
                torchaudio.save(os.path.join(args.output_path, f'{selected_voice}_{k}_{text_id}.wav'), gen.squeeze(0).cpu(), 24000)

            if args.produce_debug_state:
                os.makedirs('debug_states', exist_ok=True)
                torch.save(dbg_state, f'debug_states/do_tts_debug_{selected_voice}_{text_id}.pth')
```

config.json:

```
{
  "texts": [
    { "id": "1", "text": "First sentence" },
    { "id": "2", "text": "Second sentence" }
  ]
}
```